# Leer de una hoja Google Sheets

Tags: java, android, listview, google-hoja-de-cálculo, android-listview

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en Android usando Google Sheets como base de datos.

En mi hoja de Google Sheets tengo información almacenada sobre libros (autor, título, fecha, etc), y quiero recuperarla y que me la pinte en un `ListView`. Por una parte, he creado un objeto BookItem, y por otra tengo un adaptador `BookAdapter`. Después, en `Spreadsheets.java`, es donde tengo el método que lee de la hoja, llamado `getDataFromApi()`, que funciona, pero no sé como adaptarlo a mi `BookAdapter` y que me pinte la lista.

A continuación os dejo el código que os comento:

- BookItem

---

```
public class BookItem {
    static String title_item;
    static Drawable cover_item; //probar con String

    public BookItem(String title, Drawable cover){
        super();
        this.title_item = title;
        this.cover_item = cover;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title_item;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title){
        this.title_item = title;
    }

    public static Drawable getCover() {
        return cover_item;
    }

    public void setCover(Drawable cover) {
        this.cover_item = cover;
    }
```

- BookAdapter

---

```
public class BookAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

   //private ArrayList<BookItem> items;
    List<BookItem> items;
    private Context context;

    public BookAdapter (Context context, List<BookItem> items) {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public BookItem getItem(int position) {
        return this.items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public final ImageView cover_item;
        public final TextView title_item;

        public ViewHolder (ImageView cover_item, TextView title_item){
            this.cover_item = cover_item;
            this.title_item = title_item;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        ImageView cover_item;
        TextView title_item;

        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fila_lista_miestanteria, viewGroup, false); //se mete aqui en getView por ser baseAdapter
            title_item = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_title_item);
            cover_item = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.book_cover_item);
            view.setTag(R.id.book_title_item, title_item);
            view.setTag(R.id.book_cover_item, cover_item);
        }
        else {
            cover_item = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.book_cover_item);
            title_item = (TextView)view.getTag(R.id.book_title_item);
        }
        BookItem bookItem = getItem(position);
        cover_item.setImageDrawable(bookItem.getCover());
        title_item.setText(bookItem.getTitle());

        return view;
    }

}
```

- Spreadsheets

---

```
public class Spreadsheets extends Activity {

    static String book_title, book_author, book_date, book_category, book_description, book_rating, book_cover;
    static String read_only = "no";
    static String book_favorite = "no";
    static GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;
    private ListView bookList;
    private TextView mOutputText;
    ProgressDialog mProgress;
    Context context;
    List<String> rst;
    List<BookItem> resultados;
    BookAdapter adapter;

    private static final String[] SCOPES = {SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spread);

        // mOutputText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.outputText);
       bookList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.bookList);
        //  mOutputText.setText("");

        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgress.setMessage("Calling Google Sheets...");

        // Initialize credentials and service object.
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
                .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());

        System.out.print("read only es igual a "+ read_only);
        new MakeRequestTask(mCredential).execute();
    }

    public void rellenar(){
        System.out.println("VOY A HACER NEW BOOK ADAPTER ");
        adapter = new BookAdapter(context, resultados);
        bookList.setAdapter(adapter);
        System.out.println("SETADAPTER");
    }

    private class MakeRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {
        private Exception mLastError = null;
        MakeRequestTask(GoogleAccountCredential credential) {
        }

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                if(read_only.equals("no")) {
                    setDataToApi();
                    return null;
                }
                else {
                    return getDataFromApi();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mLastError = e;
                cancel(true);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private List<String> getDataFromApi() throws IOException {

            String range = "Sheet1!A1:H";
            List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
            ValueRange response = CreateSpreadsheets.mService.spreadsheets().values()
                    .get(CreateSpreadsheets.spreadsheet_id, range)
                    .execute();
            List<List<Object>> values = response.getValues();
            if (values != null) {
                for (List row : values) {
                    results.add(row.get(0) + ", " + row.get(7));
                }
            }
            //funcion();
            return results;
        }

        private void setDataToApi() throws IOException {

            String range = "Sheet1!A2:H";
            List<List<Object>> values = new ArrayList<>();

            List<Object> data1 = new ArrayList<>();

            data1.add(book_title);
            data1.add(book_author);
            data1.add(book_date);
            data1.add(book_category);
            data1.add(book_description);
            data1.add(book_rating);
            data1.add(book_cover);
            data1.add("a");

            values.add(data1);
            ValueRange valueRange = new ValueRange();
            valueRange.setMajorDimension("ROWS");
            valueRange.setRange(range);
            valueRange.setValues(values);

            ValueRange body = new ValueRange().setValues(values);

            AppendValuesResponse response =
                    CreateSpreadsheets.mService.spreadsheets().values().append(CreateSpreadsheets.spreadsheet_id, range, body)
                            .setValueInputOption("RAW")
                            .execute();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //mOutputText.setText("");
            mProgress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
            mProgress.hide();
            if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
                //   mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
            } else {
                if(read_only.equals("no")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Spreadsheets.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    //  mOutputText.setText("Se ha aÃ±adido un libro a su lista");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("VOY A RELLENAR LA LISTA");
                    rellenar();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCancelled() {

        }

    }
```

Mi aplicación tiene un NavigationDrawer, y desde la opción "Mi Estanteria" llamo a "Spredsheets" para que me cargue en ListView. Dejo a continuación mi MainActivity:

```
import static com.example.apptfg.CreateSpreadsheets.first_time_spread;
import static com.example.apptfg.Spreadsheets.read_only;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

private Toolbar toolbar;
Button scan_button, ok_button;
static String ean_content, title;

static String first_time = "si";
private SharedPreferences preferences = null;
int mode = Context.MODE_PRIVATE;

ImageView image_user;

String username, user_email;
TextView info_text, user, email;
View divider, header;
EditText name_input, email_input;
CheckBox remember_check;

static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
static Uri mLocationForPhotos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", mode);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLetras));
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Mi Estanteria");

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    image_user = (ImageView)header.findViewById(R.id.image_user);
    image_user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.image_user:
                    captureImage();
                    break;
         }
        }
    });

    scan_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan_button);

    //userSignIn();
    firstTime();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public void captureImage () {
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Selecciona una imagen de perfil"), REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
}

 public void firstTime(){

        if (preferences.getBoolean("hil", true)) {
            System.out.println("Entro en first time");
            AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            dialog.setTitle(R.string.title_firsttime);
            dialog.setMessage(R.string.message_firsttime);
            dialog.setPositiveButton("Sí", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    first_time_spread = first_time.toString();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CreateSpreadsheets.class);
                    intent.putExtra(first_time_spread, first_time_spread);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            dialog.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            dialog.show();
            preferences.edit().putBoolean("hil", false).apply();
        }
    }

public void userSignIn() {

    AlertDialog.Builder ad1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.user_login);


    info_text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info_text);
    divider = findViewById(R.id.divider);
    name_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name_input);
    email_input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email_input);
    remember_check = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.remember_check);
    ok_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
    ad1.setTitle(R.string.info_text);

    ok_button.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    username = name_input.getText().toString();
                    user_email = email_input.getText().toString();

                    preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", mode);
                    preferences.edit().putString("user", username).apply();
                    preferences.edit().putString("email", user_email).apply();

                    user = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.user);
                    email = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.email);

                    firstTime();
                }
            }
    );
    ad1.show();
}

public void scanBarcode(View view) {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
        intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");
        startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        showDialog(MainActivity.this, "No se ha encontrado Barcode Scanner", "¿Descargar Barcode Scanner?", "Sí", "No").show();
    }
}

private Dialog showDialog(final Activity act, CharSequence title, CharSequence message, CharSequence yes, CharSequence no) {

    AlertDialog.Builder download = new AlertDialog.Builder(act);
    download.setTitle(title);
    download.setMessage(message);
    download.setPositiveButton(yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://search?q=pname:" + "com.google.zxing.client.android");
            Intent data = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
                act.startActivity(data);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            }
        }
    });
    download.setNegativeButton(no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int i) {
        }
    });
    return download.show();
}

@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    boolean FragmentTransaction = false;

    if (id == R.id.Mi_estanteria) {
        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Spreadsheets.class);
        intent.putExtra(read_only,"si");
        startActivity(intent);
        /*getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.drawer_layout, MiEstanteria.newInstance(), MiEstanteria.TAG)
                .commit();*/
       // fragment = new MiEstanteria();
        //getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.list);
        //FragmentTransaction = true;

    }  else if (id == R.id.Escanear) {
        View view = null;
        fragment = new Escanear();
        FragmentTransaction = true;
        scanBarcode(view);

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {


    } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

    }

    if (FragmentTransaction) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, fragment).commit();
        item.setChecked(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(item.getTitle());
    }
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}


public static class Escanear extends Fragment {

    public Escanear() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_escanear, container, false);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE){
        mLocationForPhotos = data.getData();
        image_user.setImageURI(mLocationForPhotos);
    }

    if (requestCode == 0) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String format = data.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            if (format.equals("EAN_13")) {
                ean_content = contents;
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetBookInfo.class);
                intent.putExtra(ean_content, ean_content);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "El formato debe ser EAN_13", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.show();
            }
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(this, "Ha ocurrido un error escaneando", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast2.show();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();
    searchView.setQueryHint("Buscar");
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            //Se activa cuando se pulsa "Buscar"
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, GetBookInfo.class);
            title = query.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
            intent1.putExtra(title, title);
            System.out.println("El titulo es"+title);
            startActivity(intent1);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            //Se activa cuando se escribe un unico caracter
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.settings:
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ajustes.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
            return true;
        case R.id.about:
            Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
            startActivity(intent3);
            return true;
        case R.id.exit:
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).setTitle("Salir")
                    .setMessage("¿Estás seguro?").setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, null).setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            }).show();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

}

El xml "`spread`" que se infla en la Activity `Spreadsheest` es simplemente una lista, y el xml "`fila_lista_miestanteria`" consta de un `TextView` y un `ImageView` para mostrar la info de cada uno de los libros.

Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Quizá te interese intentarlo con [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=es-419), en vez de `ListView`. Es la tendencia hacia la que apunta Android: *El widget RecyclerView es una versión más flexible y avanzada de ListView. ... es un contenedor para mostrar grandes conjuntos de datos que se pueden desplazar de manera muy eficiente al mantener una cantidad limitada de vistas. Usa el widget RecyclerView cuando tengas conjuntos de datos cuyos elementos cambien en tiempo de ejecución sobre la base de la acción del usuario o los eventos de la red.*

Comment: Si te interesa, [aquí tienes un tutorial completísimo](https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-practicals/content/en/Unit%202/44_p_create_a_recycler_view.html) publicado en `google-developer`. Te explica desde cero cómo implementar un `RecyclerView`.

Comment: Ni siquiera estas rellenando la lista `resultados` que es la que pasas al adaptador. Los datos que obtienes de la hoja de calculo no los estas utilizando. Al adaptador le estas pasando una lista vacía. Y por lo que veo, los items del `ListView` tienen una imagen, de donde cargaras las imágenes que mostraras en los items? o solo utilizaras una sola imagen para todos los items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como no tengo claro lo de las imagenes solo lo hare con el texto que obtienes de la hoja de calculo.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<String> output) {
    mProgress.hide();
    if (output == null || output.size() == 0) {
        // mOutputText.setText("No results returned.");
    } else {
        if(read_only.equals("no")) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Spreadsheets.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            // mOutputText.setText("Se ha aÃ±adido un libro a su lista");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("VOY A RELLENAR LA LISTA");

            // Agregas los resultado obtenidos de la hoja de calculo
            // a la lista resultados que es la que pasas al adaptador.
            resultados = new ArrayList<>();
            for(String resultado : output) {
                resultados.add(new BookItem(resultado, null));
            }

            rellenar();
        }
    }
}
```

Con esas pocas lineas de código que agregue tu `ListView` debe de funcionar.

Comment: Hola! Las portadas de los libros también las tengo en la hoja de Google Sheet. Me gustaría recuperar el nombre del libro y la portada. He probado con lo que me has dicho, pero ahora me da un error que no entiendo muy bien lo que es y si tiene que ver con algo de esto. Muchisimas gracias por la ayuda. Dejo a continuación el error:

Comment: He editado la pregunta y he añadido también el MainActivity. Haciendo esto que me dices, me sale un error E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.apptfg.Spreadsheets has leaked window DecorView@3619e26[] that was originally added here

Comment: En que linea te marca ese error?

Comment: at com.example.apptfg.Spreadsheets$MakeRequestTask.onPreExecute(Spreadsheets.java:148)
at com.example.apptfg.Spreadsheets.onCreate(Spreadsheets.java:61)

Comment: Copia el error completo incluyendo la parte que dice CauseBy.

Comment: A continuación dejo el error completo

Comment: He conseguido que me funcione! El error estaba en que no me estaba cogiendo bien el contexto en "Spreadsheets". Muchisimas gracias!